# removing space from text in given array of string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to create numpy array from given text and the remove spaces in between the text of numpy array. How to achieve this? I am trying but not succeeded so far.

here is the data

```
array([['ALIOR', 'PLALIOR00045', '88 860 000', '1 386 216 000', '0,891',
        '2,16', '14'],
       ['CCC', 'PLCCC0000016', '27 918 000', '1 292 603 400', '0,831',
        '5,28', '42'],
       ['CDPROJEKT', 'PLOPTTC00011', '67 348 000', '22 864 646 000',
        '14,702', '7,39', '7'],
       ['CYFRPLSAT', 'PLCFRPT00013', '275 301 000', '6 854 994 900',
        '4,408', '1,17', '14'],
       ['DINOPL', 'PLDINPL00011', '47 937 000', '8 916 282 000', '5,733',
        '9,13', '12'],
       ['JSW', 'PLJSW0000015', '52 636 000', '716 902 320', '0,461',
        '1,51', '24'],
       ['KGHM', 'PLKGHM000017', '136 410 000', '9 881 540 400', '6,354',
        '4,78', '8'],
       ['LOTOS', 'PLLOTOS00025', '86 543 000', '5 609 717 260', '3,607',
        '2,91', '16'],
       ['LPP', 'PLLPP0000011', '1 306 000', '7 444 200 000', '4,787',
        '1,43', '19'],
       ['MBANK', 'PLBRE0000012', '12 997 000', '2 830 746 600', '1,820',
        '0,42', '24'],
       ['ORANGEPL', 'PLTLKPL00017', '647 357 000', '4 285 503 340',
        '2,756', '1,16', '13'],
       ['PEKAO', 'PLPEKAO00016', '176 379 000', '9 619 710 660', '6,185',
        '5,27', '9'],
       ['PGE', 'PLPGER000010', '796 776 000', '3 561 588 720', '2,290',
        '2,88', '18'],
       ['PGNIG', 'PLPGNIG00014', '1 624 608 000', '6 072 784 704',
        '3,905', '1,56', '12'],
       ['PKNORLEN', 'PLPKN0000018', '289 049 000', '17 701 360 760',
        '11,382', '12,44', '8'],
       ['PKOBP', 'PLPKO0000016', '857 593 000', '18 807 014 490',
        '12,093', '10,49', '9'],
       ['PLAY', 'LU1642887738', '114 151 000', '3 696 209 380', '2,377',
        '1,47', '16'],
       ['PZU', 'PLPZU0000011', '568 305 000', '17 515 160 100', '11,262',
        '6,64', '6'],
       ['SANPL', 'PLBZ00000044', '33 207 000', '5 213 499 000', '3,352',
        '1,91', '18'],
       ['TAURONPE', 'PLTAURN00011', '1 043 590 000', '1 252 308 000',
        '0,805', '1,21', '33']], dtype='<U14')
```

task is.. in the given array if any text contains spaces in between them remove the space. If any text contains "," then remove the comma and replace it with the period(.). For example: in the given array, first row have string like '88 860 000' then it should be like '88860000' and '0,891' should be like '0.891'

I have tried multiple methods but not able to achieve it.

Comment: Unless you want to perform a fixed position operation, there is no way to vectorize this, you'll have to loop

Comment: @mozway Can you check my answer? It was quite straight-forward for me to vectorize it

Comment: @TinoD this is not true vectorization `np.vectorize` is a wrapper around a loop

Comment: @mozway oh okay, so I guess my answer was wrong :/

Comment: @TinoD I'd have done more or less the same, but don't falsely believe that this is true vectorization (quoting the docs: "*The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.*"). Not sure what OP's teacher is expecting here.

Comment: @mozway I guess a way to do it without loops

Comment: Without **explicit** loops ;)

Comment: Since this is a 2d array of strings, the use of `vectorize` is prettier than the equivalent list comprehension, even if it isn't faster..  `Numpy` doesn't have much specialized string code of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function:

```
def process_text(text):
    return text.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.') # replace the space and coma
```

And here is how to you it:

```
processed_data = np.vectorize(process_text)(data) # use function on data
```

The results:

```
[['ALIOR' 'PLALIOR00045' '88860000' '1386216000' '0.891' '2.16' '14']
 ['CCC' 'PLCCC0000016' '27918000' '1292603400' '0.831' '5.28' '42']
 ['CDPROJEKT' 'PLOPTTC00011' '67348000' '22864646000' '14.702' '7.39' '7']
 ['CYFRPLSAT' 'PLCFRPT00013' '275301000' '6854994900' '4.408' '1.17' '14']
 ['DINOPL' 'PLDINPL00011' '47937000' '8916282000' '5.733' '9.13' '12']
 ['JSW' 'PLJSW0000015' '52636000' '716902320' '0.461' '1.51' '24']
 ['KGHM' 'PLKGHM000017' '136410000' '9881540400' '6.354' '4.78' '8']
 ['LOTOS' 'PLLOTOS00025' '86543000' '5609717260' '3.607' '2.91' '16']
 ['LPP' 'PLLPP0000011' '1306000' '7444200000' '4.787' '1.43' '19']
 ['MBANK' 'PLBRE0000012' '12997000' '2830746600' '1.820' '0.42' '24']
 ['ORANGEPL' 'PLTLKPL00017' '647357000' '4285503340' '2.756' '1.16' '13']
 ['PEKAO' 'PLPEKAO00016' '176379000' '9619710660' '6.185' '5.27' '9']
 ['PGE' 'PLPGER000010' '796776000' '3561588720' '2.290' '2.88' '18']
 ['PGNIG' 'PLPGNIG00014' '1624608000' '6072784704' '3.905' '1.56' '12']
 ['PKNORLEN' 'PLPKN0000018' '289049000' '17701360760' '11.382' '12.44'
  '8']
 ['PKOBP' 'PLPKO0000016' '857593000' '18807014490' '12.093' '10.49' '9']
 ['PLAY' 'LU1642887738' '114151000' '3696209380' '2.377' '1.47' '16']
 ['PZU' 'PLPZU0000011' '568305000' '17515160100' '11.262' '6.64' '6']
 ['SANPL' 'PLBZ00000044' '33207000' '5213499000' '3.352' '1.91' '18']
 ['TAURONPE' 'PLTAURN00011' '1043590000' '1252308000' '0.805' '1.21' '33']]
```

I defined data like this:

```
data = np.array([
    ['ALIOR', 'PLALIOR00045', '88 860 000', '1 386 216 000', '0,891', '2,16', '14'],
    ['CCC', 'PLCCC0000016', '27 918 000', '1 292 603 400', '0,831', '5,28', '42'],
    ['CDPROJEKT', 'PLOPTTC00011', '67 348 000', '22 864 646 000', '14,702', '7,39', '7'],
    ['CYFRPLSAT', 'PLCFRPT00013', '275 301 000', '6 854 994 900', '4,408', '1,17', '14'],
    ['DINOPL', 'PLDINPL00011', '47 937 000', '8 916 282 000', '5,733', '9,13', '12'],
    ['JSW', 'PLJSW0000015', '52 636 000', '716 902 320', '0,461', '1,51', '24'],
    ['KGHM', 'PLKGHM000017', '136 410 000', '9 881 540 400', '6,354', '4,78', '8'],
    ['LOTOS', 'PLLOTOS00025', '86 543 000', '5 609 717 260', '3,607', '2,91', '16'],
    ['LPP', 'PLLPP0000011', '1 306 000', '7 444 200 000', '4,787', '1,43', '19'],
    ['MBANK', 'PLBRE0000012', '12 997 000', '2 830 746 600', '1,820', '0,42', '24'],
    ['ORANGEPL', 'PLTLKPL00017', '647 357 000', '4 285 503 340', '2,756', '1,16', '13'],
    ['PEKAO', 'PLPEKAO00016', '176 379 000', '9 619 710 660', '6,185', '5,27', '9'],
    ['PGE', 'PLPGER000010', '796 776 000', '3 561 588 720', '2,290', '2,88', '18'],
    ['PGNIG', 'PLPGNIG00014', '1 624 608 000', '6 072 784 704', '3,905', '1,56', '12'],
    ['PKNORLEN', 'PLPKN0000018', '289 049 000', '17 701 360 760', '11,382', '12,44', '8'],
    ['PKOBP', 'PLPKO0000016', '857 593 000', '18 807 014 490', '12,093', '10,49', '9'],
    ['PLAY', 'LU1642887738', '114 151 000', '3 696 209 380', '2,377', '1,47', '16'],
    ['PZU', 'PLPZU0000011', '568 305 000', '17 515 160 100', '11,262', '6,64', '6'],
    ['SANPL', 'PLBZ00000044', '33 207 000', '5 213 499 000', '3,352', '1,91', '18'],
    ['TAURONPE', 'PLTAURN00011', '1 043 590 000', '1 252 308 000', '0,805', '1,21', '33']
], dtype='<U14')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling str.replace multiple times, it might be better to use maketrans / translate. In this case there are only two characters that need to be replaced and so calling replace twice is no big deal. However, when the number of replacements increases (or is otherwise more complex) then the aforementioned technique is likely to be more appropriate.

Assume your data are in a numpy array called my_array then:

```
from numpy import vectorize

t = str.maketrans({" ": "", ",":"."})

my_new_array = vectorize(lambda s: s.translate(t))(my_array)
```

**Note:**

Whilst maketrans / translate is easy to use, it is notoriously slow